# java: ArrayList() method returning a result : if passing argument or without passing it

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to write the method listCopies() that returns in an ArrayList all copies of a written work in a given language(eg : english); if no language is given (empty string), all copies of the library will be returned (in all languages) .
This is the code i have developed but it doesnt work cause in the main(String[] args) {...} it calls 2 times this method , one with the argument passed and in the second without an argument  :

```
public ArrayList<Exemplary> listCopies(String l){
    ArrayList <Exemplary> tmp = new ArrayList<Exemplary>();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < copies.size(); i++){  
                 if(copies.get(i).getWrittenWork().getLanguage().equals(language)){ 
                tmp.add(Ex);
             }
    }
    return (tmp);}
```

I want to rewrite this code in a way that with or without argument (String lang) >  it returns the array tmp .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Side note, you have `String lang` passed to the method, but referenced an `language` in the code of the method.

Comment: *if no language is given (empty string), all copies of the library will be returned (in all languages)*: you haven't implemented this rule. Just do it.

Comment: `if(language.equals(""))` put a check in this way.

Comment: i am looking to get the right method because this one doesn't work

Comment: Use your debugger, add traces in the code, to understand how, and why it doesn't work. That's the job of a developer. You'd better get used to it. You've already been given several hints in these comments.

Comment: Are having problem compiling your code? If yes, then what's the problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet   how to do it , if i do that : public ArrayList<Exemplary> listCopies(){.....} , it returns me an error

Comment: I am a newbie in java , that's why i don't understand how to use a debugger

Comment: I am looking to write this method in such manner , if passed or no an argument it gives a result cause in : public static void main(String[] args) {...}.there is a same method which in a time give the argument to this listCopies() method  & in another line it didn't give the argument.

Comment: System.out.println("La bibliotheque " + biblio.getNom() + " offre ");
        afficherExemplaires(biblio.listerExemplaires());
        String langue = "anglais";
        System.out.println("Les exemplaires en " + langue + " sont  ");
        afficherExemplaires(biblio.listerExemplaires(langue));
        System.out.println("Les auteurs a succes sont  ");
        biblio.afficherAuteur();
        System.out.print("Il y a " + biblio.compterExemplaires(o3) + " exemplaires");
        System.out.println(" de  " + o3.getTitre());

Comment: excuse me because it is written in french

Answer (score 1):

There's a multitude of problems with your code:

- `lang` is used on the first line, but further on you use `language`
- `Exemplary` is used on the first line, but on the 2nd you use `Exemplairy`
- the method doesn't have a closing `}` at the end
- you don't have code that deals with an empty language
- the loop should be rewritten as an [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)
- [the interface `List` should be used instead of the class `ArrayList` where possible](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html)

Comment: public ArrayList<Exemplaire> listerExemplaires(String l){
  ArrayList <Exemplaire> tmp = new ArrayList<Exemplaire>();
  for( int i = 0 ; i < exemplaires.size(); i++){  
    if(exemplaires.get(i).getOeuvre().getLangue().equals(langue)){ 
     tmp.add(Ex);
     }
  }
  return (tmp);
 }

Comment: please take a look again to my question above , i gave more explanations to my problem